# Energy Spectrogram with non-evenly spaced values on Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, spectrogram

I'm trying to plot a time-frequency-energy distribution plot (basically a spectogram); however, in my case I have the arrays with values for frequency and energy already determined (so there's no need to use the spectrogram function in matplotlib and my the thing I'm working with is already sampled so time is just the number of points in the array).

Here's a very basic example of what these arrays might look like:

```
time = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
freq = [ [ 5, 8, 10, 13, 19, 21]  , [1.3, 3.4, 8.9, 18.3, 45.4, 43.9] ] 
amp = [ [ 2.3 , 4.7,  9.1 ,  10.3, 3.2, 1.2],  [7.4 , 1.1 , 4.5 , 6.6, 8.9 , 6.7] ]
```

in my actual implementation my time array would be really big (like 216,000 points long) and so my frequency and amplitude arrays would be an array of N (I set N = 2 in the basic example above) arrays of 216,000 points long. Note that the values in frequency and amplitude aren't evenly spaced so I don't think I can do a meshgrid or surface plot (pretty sure meshgrid breaks with too many points). Let me know if I should provide more information.